# How to add a property to type?

Tags: typescript

I have to work with a code which present a recurrent situation like next example:

```js
const orders: Order[] = await this.getOrders()

const parsedOrders = orders.map(order => {
  // @ts-ignore --> how to remove this line without getting errors
  order.linesLength = order.lines.length
  return order
})
```

I would like to remove the indicated comment and let TypeScript do its work without generating errors. But I'm not sure what kind of technique implement in these situations when I have a type to which I need to add some property that doesn't exist in it.

Comment: `parsedOrders` is undefined, `forEach` doesn't return anything; why not use `orders.map` rather than mutating `orders`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe my error! I edit my post. Anyway, `orders.map`  trigger the same behavior

Comment: Why don't you create a *new object* instead of mutating the old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface that extends `Order` with the additional properties:

```js
interface ParsedOrder extends Order {
  linesLength: number
}

const parsedOrders: ParsedOrder[] = orders.map((order) => {
  return {
    ...order,
    linesLength: order.lines.length
  }
})
```